# Widget Logic use with Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, widgets

I am using Widget Logic and attempting to use the new WPAdverts plugin to display classified ads.

They use a custom taxonomy of `taxonomy=advert_category&post_type=advert`.

I'm trying to display a widget only when a category is in a certain category but I can't seem to figure out the syntax?

According to the Codex and Widget Logic's FAQ this should work fine? What am I missing?

```
is_advert( 'advert_category', 'hilton-head') && is_single() && get_post_type()=='advert')
```

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpadverts/